# Adding an 'active-class' to a list which is inputted by user

Tags: javascript

Hello im new to Javascript and trying out some different things. 
I have a ul which the user can input some li:s.

My goal is to set a li class of active and then removing it by referencing it to the active class. Like a To-Do list but light.

I've tried alot of different approaches and the code below is what I got right now which isn't working properly... The first function just adds things to the list and the second should give a li element the class of active. 
The removing part I'm hoping to solve by myself..

Im very thankful for any input. Thanks!

```
function addElementLast (){
let textValue = document.getElementById('candidate').value;
if(textValue == ''){
    alert('Type something')
}else{
    let newLi = document.createElement('li')
    newLi.setAttribute('class', 'toggle');
    let get = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(textValue);
    newLi.appendChild(textNode);
    get.appendChild(newLi);
}}
     var parent = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
     var child = parent.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
     for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
     child[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
     if (current.length > 0) { 
     current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
     }
     this.className += " active";
     });
     }

     document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addElementLast)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Adding to ul</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2 id="heading" class="text-center">Adding to UL</h2>
            <ul id="dynamic-list">

            </ul>
        <input type="text" id="candidate" placeholder="Write here">
        <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-success">Add item</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-danger">Remove item</button>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off if you manipulated a list in JS and just rendered an HTML "template" to the UI.

It's faster, easier to keep track of items and much easier to change the algorithms.

```js
let todoList = []

// adding to the todo list
function addTodo(s, arr) {
  if (s) {
    arr.push({
      text: s,
      active: false
    })
  }
  return arr
}

// creating the html that should be rendered
function createTodoListHTML(arr) {
  let html = ''
  arr.forEach(e => {
    const active = e.active ? ' active' : ''
    html += `<li class="item${active}">${e.text}</li>`
  })
  return html
}

// rendering the list
function displayTodoList(html) {
  document.getElementById('dynamic-list').innerHTML = html
  activate(todoList)
}

// handling add item btn click
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let input = document.getElementById('candidate')
  addTodo(input.value, todoList)
  displayTodoList(createTodoListHTML(todoList))
  input.value = ''
})

// adding event listener to li items
function activate(list) {
  const children = document.querySelectorAll('#dynamic-list .item')
  children.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
      todoList[i].active = !todoList[i].active
      displayTodoList(createTodoListHTML(todoList))
    })
  })
}



// removing items from the list and the UI
const btnRemove = document.getElementById('btn1')

btnRemove.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  todoList = removeItems(todoList)
  displayTodoList(createTodoListHTML(todoList))
})

function removeItems(arr) {
  return arr.filter(e => !e.active)
}
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2 id="heading" class="text-center">Adding to UL</h2>
  <ul id="dynamic-list">

  </ul>
  <input type="text" id="candidate" placeholder="Write here">
  <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-success">Add item</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-danger">Remove item</button>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks thats looks good but a bit to advanced for me but I think I got the hang of it. 
I have some questions about the code. Can I ask you here or do you prefer something else?

Comment: It's good here - if it becomes lengthy, then we can move the discussion to chat

Comment: Thanks buddy. The thing im wondering about the most is where the functions arguments get passed in and where they are referencing to in the code. Do you think you could describe a bit more what the function do. 
And also the 'e' and the 'el' arguments. Because it seems like they dont get used in the function but they clearly work.
For example the function activate. The argument (list) what does that reference?

Comment: I’ll write the answer in parts - as I have time :)

Comment: So, the basic idea is that I don’t want to modify the DOM (the UI), only when I know that something has to be modified there. Modifying the DOM is an “expensive” action, so do the things you can “inside” JS. That’s why I defined a **todoList** array of objects. I keep and update all the data there. It’s the core of this “component”.

Comment: Then I need three functions: add todo, remove todo**s**, and render the actual **todoList**

Comment: **addTodo** function requires the **todoList** (arr), the string of the item to add (s), and returns the modified **todoList** (arr). Each item also has an **active** attribute, because later on we’ll need to be able to choose one or more of the items in the **todoList**, and that requires a “flag”

Comment: **removeTodos** only needs the **todoList**, as the items hold information about their own removal (active: true or active:false). It returns a new (filtered) array

Comment: rendering is made up of two functions: one that assembles the HTML to be added to the DOM, the other that actually handles the created HTML (replaces the elements in the `<ul>` (these are: **createTodoListHTML** and **displayTodoList**, respectively)

Comment: then there are two click event handlers for the two buttons (**addEventListener**s) - one for adding the input value to the **todoList**, the other is for removing **active items** from the list

Comment: the **activate** function is a necessity: as we handle dynamically rendered elements in the DOM, we have to bind click events to them, when they are created. **activate** does exactly that. Its handler is a function that toggles the **active** value of the clicked item (active = !active), and then renders the actual list

Comment: this is all the functions there are: **add item** to list,**remove items** from list, **create HTML**, **add HTML to DOM**, **add button** event handler, **remove button** event handler, **binding event handlers** to dynamic elements; and we have one core item: the **todoList**, that is "passed around" (as list, todoList, arr, etc.)

Comment: the variable **e** you see (or sometimes: **el**) is kind of an "implicit variable": `forEach()`, `map()`, `filter()`, `find()`, `reduce()` - they all have this. These functions iterate over an array (or something array-like), and **e** is the item they currently hold (on every iteration). So on the first iteration **e** is the first item of the array, on the second iteration **e** is the second item of the array, etc. Actually `forEach()` looks like this: `forEach((e, i, d) => {})` - **e**: element, **i**: index, **d** the array being iterated. (`reduce()` looks a bit different)

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's **e**, **el**, **item**, **element** or **catMeow** - the important thing is that it holds the value of the item that is currently being iterated over

Comment: Thanks for the effort Muka its greatly appreciated!
Do you have any idea on how to build on top of your code to implement som new features that I can practice on?

Comment: The core is the **todoList**, you could **order it alphabetically** (toggle ascending-descending order). Then try to expand the **object that is an item in the todoList** - now it has a **text** and an **active** attribute, but you could add a value, a timestamp, an id (unique!), and work with those: order the list, filter the list, group the list by any attribute, and you could also modify the HTML string (in `createTodoListHTML()`) to display the extra attributes you added.

Comment: Then there could be a more advanced thing: create a **PUBSUB** around it, and include your functions in multiple parts of your page. (Source: https://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript) But this is when you feel you have control of JS, and want to learn concepts.

Comment: And then there's of course React, Vue, Angular... (I'd suggest Vue - maybe the most friendly of these.) If you start working with these, then you'll really see the "power" of a central "store" on the frontend (like the **todoList** here).

Comment: But I forgot one thing: try to fill up the **todoList** from an API, like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ - it would require **async** functions. Maybe hard at first, but when you get the feel of it you can integrate ANY resource into your (web)app.

Comment: Super! Really appreciate all your help! 
I will try this!